# Unit of work Update problem: Entity Already another instance is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

I've a problem with my **UOW pattern** implementation ( my UOW uses Repository Pattern ). Im gonna try to explain my project structure with two simple calsses.
I've Person and Car, (one to many - one to one).

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public IList<Car> cars_owned{ get; set; }

}
```

and

```
[Table("Car")]
public class Car
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public Person owner{ get; set; }
}
```

In my CarServiceImplementation I want to implement my **AddUpdateCar()** in order to add a "Person" if it doesn't exists or update it.

This is my actually implementation:

```
public async Task<bool> addUpdateCar(AddUpdateCarModel model)
        {
            var car = await unitOfWork.CarRepository.GetByID(model.car_id);
            var person = await unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetByID(model.person.id);
            if (person == null)
            {
                unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Insert(model.person);
            }
            else
            {
                unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Update(model.person);
            }

            car.owner = model.person;
            unitOfWork.CarRepository.Update(car);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return true;
        }
```

**This kind of impl says:** The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'id'} is already being tracked.

I've also tryed differnt ways but I've got other issues.

**Which is the right way to implement this method?**

**EDIT 1:**

```
public void Update(Person p)
{
    context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

and

```
public async Task<Person> GetByID(int id)
        {
            return await context.person.FindAsync(id);
        }
```

Comment: pls post your unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Update(model.person);  and GetById code pls

Comment: Edit 1, thaks for answer

Comment: @Limitless a little off topic but why do you hide repositories from your services  behind UOW object? Is it for the sake of simplicity (otherwise you would need to inject each and every repository explicitly into your app services)? I wonder if being explicit is a better design decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a unit of work, the easiest way would be to add a new method to PersonRepository

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Person p)
{
    var existedPerson = GetByID(p.id);
    if (existedPerson != null) 
        context.Entry(existedPerson).CurrentValues.SetValues(p);
    else Insert(p);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats works. I was focused on services instead repository.